# changing multiple values in a row while iterating the list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, row

I need to change multiple values in a row for multiple rows in a list.
I came up with this, but it's not working.

file is a list of lists.

```
new_file = []
value_1 = 'title'
value_2 = '1'
value_3 = '1'

for row in file:
    new_file.append(row[:5] + value_1 + value_2 + value_3)
```

Comment: what is the structure of  `file`?

Comment: Please see [mcve]. A sample input and the desired output would make answering this much easier...

Comment: What is the datatype of `row`? Is it a list, string or something else?

Comment: file is a list of lists so row is a list an each element in the row is a string. I need to change the three strings at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If `row` is a list, then you can't use the `+` operator to append string elements to the end of it. You'll need to group the three strings into a list to add them to the end of `row`. Try this:

```
for row in file:
    new_file.append(row[:5] + [value_1, value_2, value_3])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you dealing with a 2D List and calling it 'new_file'. If you are creating the values in new_file for the first time then this would work:

```
value_1 = 'title'
value_2 = '1'
value_3 = '1'

new_file =[[value_1, value_2, value_3] for i in range(5)]

print(new_file)
```